# Can't browse/open .aspx pages

Tags: asp.net, html, iis, localhost

I'm having this problem on a new cruisecontrol.net install running on Windows Server 2003 where I cannot browse to http://localhost/ccnet/default.aspx.

I can, however, browse/open .html files, just not .aspx pages.

The errors I get when trying to access .aspx pages are:

> In IE: "Internet Explorer cannot
>   display the web page".
>
> In Chrome: "Error 101:
>   ERR_CONNECTION_RESET".

I've done the aspnet_regiis thing and double-checked my web extensions. Web extensions show as "ASP.NET 1.1.4322" and "ASP.NET 2.0.50727", both set to "Allowed".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... sort of. The solution (if you want to call it that) was to uninstall IIS, reinstall IIS, then reinstall Windows 2003 Server SP2. After that, works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You may get a Page cannot be found message when you browse aspx pages in a Windows Server 2003 environment.

That is because in Windows 2003, all the webservice extensions are "Prohibited" by default to ensure security.

To resolve this, do the following steps:-

1. From your Run command, type inetmgr and press enter.
2. Expand the appropriate nodes in the IIS to locate the "Webservice Extensions" Node
3. Click on the same.
4. You will find a list of "prohibited" extensions in the right.
5. Click on ASP.NET and "allow" it

That should resolve this issue.

This applies for Windows Server 2003, IIS 6.0 environment.

*pulled from: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200109170253/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/ranganh/archive/2005/04/25/37597.aspx)*

Comment: I have both "ASP.NET 1.1.4322" and "ASP.NET 2.0.50727", both set to "Allowed" already.